# Which class name to use for code-behind file for index.razor in blazor?

Tags: blazor, code-behind

When I split up a razor file into .razor and .razor.cs, I usually
1.) name the page in the .razor like e.g.

```
@page "/pagecreateuser"
```

and
2.) in the .razor.cs file, I name the class e.g.

```
public class PageCreateUser
```

This works fine...

But now I want to split up my index.razor file.
In the index.razor, the page is named

```
@page "/"
```

Which class name can I use in the index.razor.cs file? I cannot leave it empty...

Comment: The page is a class of type `Index` so the code behind is `Index.razor.cs`

Comment: You can create a file named, ```Index.razor.cs``` then in the file change class type to ```pubic partial class Index```. So in the code behind-class, you will have to use the name of the file.
(In case you don't know what partial is, it extends the class wha it is named after)

Comment: Using "Index" as class name worked. Thx!

Comment: In the future, please elaborate on what you tried, and what the result was. That helps question answerers.